What's this movie
It's set in ancient times, the opening is a woman having her baby cut from her stomach and he's more of a monster than human. The father puts the creature underground with a single pipe for entry in the middle of his "throne room" they sacrifice younger girls to it. A few people go down there and end up blowing up the tunnels and the monster and survive only buy diving in a pool of water (older movie)

To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you watched the movie or TV show (even an approximate year or decade is helpful), and what movies or TV shows you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

Could this be The Keep (1983)? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Keep_(film)
